# WINFORM not inserting into SQL - Cant find anything wrong

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am pretty new to C# and have created a small data entry form for my company in order to replace a heavy paper process. I have created an XML version and a MySQL version (at home) that runs ok but would rather link to our MS SQL server which I can then combine use with SSRS and other software. The form has two connections, one for populating a combobox (but not write back too) and the other connection links to a table with which to insert the form data.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace order4
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        categorycombo.Items.Add("BUS");
        categorycombo.Items.Add("KIT");
        categorycombo.Items.Add("MISC");
        replacementcombo.Items.Add("YES");
        replacementcombo.Items.Add("NO");
    }
    void cleardata()
    {
        itemtxt.Clear();
        itemdetailstxt.Clear();
        itemdetails2txt.Clear();
        termtxt.Clear();
        costtxt.Clear();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //fills combobox with customer info.    this.vw_order_1617TableAdapter.Fill(this.businessReportsDataSet.vw_order_1617);
    }

    private void Insert()
    {
        try
        {
        string connectionString = "server=ruby;" + "initial catalog=businessReports;" + "user id=SSRSxrubyxREADER;" + "password=XXXX";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO order_1617 VALUES(" + "@customerid,@category,@item,@itemdetails,@itemdetails2,@term,@replacement,@cost)", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerid", sidcombo.GetItemText(sidcombo.SelectedItem));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", categorycombo.GetItemText(categorycombo.SelectedItem));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", itemtxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemdetails", itemdetailstxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemdetails2", itemdetails2txt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@term", termtxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cost", costtxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@replacement", replacementcombo.GetItemText(replacementcombo.SelectedItem));
                int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("THIS HAS BEEN SAVED");
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            //Log exception
            }
        }

    private void save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Insert();
    }
    private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'businessReportsDataSet.vw_order_1617' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.vw_order_1617TableAdapter.Fill(this.businessReportsDataSet.vw_order_1617);

        }
    }
}
```

I have been going over this and really cannot find why it won't allow the data to be inserted.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you encountering any errors? Are you sure you are using the correct connection string? Also, move your `conn.Close();` outside of your `SqlCommand` `using statement`

Comment: Are you getting an exception? If so, what is it?

Comment: Do you get the messagebox with "this has been saved"? What is stored in the local variable `int rows` after execution?

Comment: Not getting an exception message at all or even if its saved. The save_btn clicks but nothing gets entered.

Comment: Add MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); to your catch clause.  I find it hard to believe no exception is generated if the operation fails.

Comment: The int row was just a remnant of something from before, dont need it now.

Comment: Set breakpoint on `Insert()` call. It could be a stupid mistake, like if you forget to wire up event handler (`Click` event of `save_btn`).

Comment: Figured it out, the save_btn's name was slightly off with the code :( I am a frigging idiot :( thanks for all the help guys btw

Comment: Consider using Visual Studio to build your forms and data binding from DataSources: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwh8ka92(v=vs.100).aspx  The WinForms tools work fine for simple single table editing tasks. (I assume these work with C# - I'm a VB users.)

Comment: I already use visual studio and this is a winform using c#. Not sure the point of your message..